# Windows 8 post image to a web server

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8

I have the following JavaScript code to get contact name and thumbnail from the people app.

```
 var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
 picker.commitButtonText = "Select";
 picker.pickSingleContactAsync().done(function (contact) {
 if (contact !== null) {
     var name = contact.name
     contact.getThumbnailAsync().done(function (thumbnail) {
         if (thumbnail.size > 0) {
             var imageBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(thumbnail);
             document.getElementById("img").src = imageBlob; 
             WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://host?name=" + name }).done(
                 function completed(rss) {

                 },
                 function error(request) {
                    // handle error conditions.
                 },
                 function progress(request) {
                    // report on progress of download.
                 }
             ); 
         }
     });
 }
```

I know ho to send the name to a web server but how to send the thumbnail ?

Can somebody provide a sample code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a HTTP POST with WinJS.xhr().  Here's an example:

[How to upload binary data with WinJS.xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635240.aspx)

You just set these options: `type: "POST", url: <URI of the website>, data: blob`.  Create the blob first, as shown in the example.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but can I post a string along with the image blob for example user ID so I know which user is making the post ?

Comment: You can just include `user: username` in the options.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx.

Comment: Thank you again, There is no data sent to the server I tried with the following code `var blob = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream("image/bmp", thumbnail);` and on the php side `file_put_contents("$path",base64_decode($_POST['data']))`

Comment: Use Fiddler to look at the traffic from the client to the server.  http://www.fiddler2.com.  Is the payload really empty?  Try setting a breakpoint and inspect the `blob` variable.

Comment: I see that the image binary data is sent to the server the Content-Length is 9594 and there is a data starting with PNG, but the image on the server is still empty

Comment: I have managed to save the image to a file the PHP code is `file_put_contents("$path",file_get_contents("php://input"));`. Thank You.